# How to write JsValue?

Tags: scala, playframework, json4s

I have a case class like this:

`case class BadResponse(message:String,errorCode:Integer,errors:Option[JsValue])`

it seem that json4s write does not understand JsValue:

`write(BadResponse(messagesApi("error_form"),10001,Some(error.errorsAsJson)))`

return

`{"message":"Form Error","errorCode":10001,"errors":{}}` although `Logger.debug(error.errorsAsJson.toString)` shows a list of errors

Is there an implementation to make json4s write `play.api.libs.json.JsValue` properly?

I'm thinking about converting JsValue to JValue (which is json4s based object), but I also don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I replaced

`error.errorsAsJson` 
by `org.json4s.native.JsonMethods.parse(error.errorsAsJson.toString)`

and changed

`case class BadResponse(message:String,errorCode:Integer,errors:Option[JsValue])`

to

`case class BadResponse(message:String,errorCode:Integer,errors:Option[JValue])`